# How to remove the direction and save view from google map

Tags: html, google-maps

My google map view currently looks something like this

[image]

We can see a white box at left top indicating the directions and save option.
I want to remove that view part.
How to do that?
This is the piece of code I am using currently:

```
<div class="image-display" id="displaylocate" style=" width:100%; height:100%;right:0%;top:0%;position:absolute;z-index:1;"> 
    <iframe width="100%" height="87%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://www.google.co.in/maps?t=m&amp;q=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Vaikunthlal+Mehta+Rd,+Nehru+Nagar,+Airport+Area,+Juhu,+Mumbai,+Mumbai+Suburban,+Maharashtra&amp;z=14&amp;ll=19.104093,72.840396&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do this with a standard Google map in an iframe. If you want to make a custom map, use the Maps API.

Comment: thanks for saving the precious time.